# Graficas con Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html5, chart.js

Tengo un pequeño problema con las gráficas , lo que sucede es lo siguiente , tengo una lista donde dicha lista en cada elemento tiene un botón que muestra en unas pestañas mas información sobre cada elemento , siempre que se le da click en el botón se carga en una pestaña la gráfica que he realizado , la cuestión es que esa gráfica cada que la muestro una vez y regreso a la lista a mirar otro ítem se recarga la gráfica pero encima de la que ya existía, alguna ayuda ?

He leido que puede ser lo del canvas , pero no se como limpiarlo, agradezco la ayuda

Adiciono la informacion solicitada con respecto al codigo:

Tengo el codigo con el que grafico :

```
require(['assets/bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js'], function(Chart){

            var ctx = $("#myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'bar',
              data: {
                  borderWidth:2,
                  labels: that.label,
                  datasets: [{

                      data: that.arrayValorSolicitud
                      } 
                  ]
              },
              options: {
                  scales: {
                      yAxes: [{
                          ticks: {
                              beginAtZero:true
                          }
                      }]
                  }
              }
          });
        })
```

Tengo el elemento que deseo que cuando se de click se cree la grafica en base al codigo anterior

```
<a  target="_self"  href="#infoPersonal" aria-controls="infoPersonal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="formCtrl.getCredito(credit); formCtrl.getFlujoCaja(credit)" id="prueba"><span class="botonSiguiente glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right btn-lg"></span></a>
```

Y tengo el elemento donde se refleja el grafico

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="auto" height="auto"></canvas>
```

Se debe tener presente el hecho de que es una lista que se llena utilizando angular y consumiendo web service, cada item que se crea tiene esa etiqueta que corresponde a un boton , donde cada que se le de click a ese boton se debe crear la grafica , cuando le doy a uno cualquiera pero que sea el primero en ser clickeado se grafica perfecto , pero cuando regreso a la lista y clickeo otro la grafica se muestra encima de la anterior, no esta de mas obviamente indicarles que la grafica se esta llenando en base a dos arrays uno es arrayValorSolicitud[] y el otro es label[] , ambos igual deben reiniciarse tal como se limpia la grafica

Comment: Puedes compartir el código ?

Comment: probablemente te esté faltando limpiar el canvas

Comment: Estaría genial que compartieras un fiddle replicando lo que estás haciendo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya la publique como una respuesta , gracias

Answer (score 2):

Aquí la solución, a que si la gráfica se coloca encima de la otra.

```
if ( window.myChart != undefined){
    window.myChart.destroy();
}
window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    .........
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Prueba limpiando el div antes de generar un nuevo chart

        var ctx = $("#myChart");
        ctx.empty();

    o

        $("#myChart").empty();
        var ctx = $("#myChart");

    Antes de 

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, [...]</del>

Veo, después de tu edición que estás usando Angular por lo que te recomendaría usar ng-chart o ng2-charts dependiendo si estas usando AngularJS o Angular.

Te dejo los links para que puedas ver la documentación, ejemplos e implemetarlo de manera correcta en tu proyecto.

[AngularJS](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

[Angular](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

Espero te sirva. :)

Comment: No funciona amigo :s

Comment: Comparte el código completo, a ver si nos acercamos al error

Comment: Por cuestiones laborales no se me permite , lo siento.

Comment: Hay formas de hacer un ejemplo, sin necesidad de mostrar información sensible para la empresa, vamos que puedes

Comment: ya la publique como una respuesta, gracias

Comment: Buen día Fabián, ahi edite mi respuesta, espero que te sirva, sino no dudes en seguir consultando

Answer (score -1):

Tengo el codigo con el que grafico :

```
  require(['assets/bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js'], function(Chart){

                var ctx = $("#myChart");
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                  type: 'bar',
                  data: {
                      borderWidth:2,
                      labels: that.label,
                      datasets: [{

                          data: that.arrayValorSolicitud
                          } 
                      ]
                  },
                  options: {
                      scales: {
                          yAxes: [{
                              ticks: {
                                  beginAtZero:true
                              }
                          }]
                      }
                  }
              });
            })
```

Tengo el elemento que deseo que cuando se de click se cree la grafica en base al codigo anterior

```
<a  target="_self"  href="#infoPersonal" aria-controls="infoPersonal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="formCtrl.getCredito(credit); formCtrl.getFlujoCaja(credit)" id="prueba"><span class="botonSiguiente glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right btn-lg"></span></a>
```

Y tengo el elemento donde se refleja el grafico

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="auto" height="auto"></canvas>
```

Se debe tener presente el hecho de que es una lista que se llena utilizando angular y consumiendo web service, cada item que se crea tiene esa etiqueta  que corresponde a un boton , donde cada que se le de click a ese boton se debe crear la grafica , cuando le doy a uno cualquiera pero que sea el primero en ser clickeado se grafica perfecto , pero cuando regreso a la lista y clickeo otro la grafica se muestra encima de la anterior, no esta de mas obviamente indicarles que la grafica se esta llenando en base a dos arrays uno es arrayValorSolicitud[] y el otro es label[] , ambos igual deben reiniciarse tal como se limpia la grafica

Comment: Disculpa pero, ¿esto es información adicional a tu pregunta?, si es así, debes **editar tu pregunta**; si esto es una respuesta, te sugiero mejorar la redacción y luego aceptar tu respuesta. Saludos.